# Using for loop for different user input options

Tags: python, for-loop

I'd like to shorten my code significantly by using a for loop to allow a player to buy a shop item labeled by number. The shop can have between 3-5 items. With my current code if you type in '1' the code will work fine, but the other items are in-accessible.

```
command = input()


def buy():
    for x in range(1, 6):
        c = str(x)
        e = x
        return (c, e)

c, e = buy()
f = e - 1
if command == c:
    inv_items.append(items[f])
    print(e)
    print(inv_items)
    buy_more = input('Would you like to buy anything else?')
```

I'm not sure how to fix the indentation when i paste the code here. But my indentation is correct.

Comment: The `return` statement will end the function in the first iteration, so the second iteration will never occur

Comment: Thank you I changed indentation of the return and it is working now.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Okay it worked once and now for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: You probably put the return outside the for. That way, it will only work when x=6.. What exactly do you want the `buy` function to do?